# C Program prints erroneous data in output file possibly due to lack of memory

Tags: c, file, memory-management, singly-linked-list

I use the DOSBox Turbo C compiler.

I coded for a program to read characters from a text file which'd contain a novel, separating words alphabetically in the process, and adding these words to respective alphabet nodes. When a word is repeated, the 'count' of the node containing that word is incremented. My idea was to identify the most used words for each alphabet.

However, I found that due to possible memory limitations of this compiler, after a certain number of words, only (null)'s were stored in the nodes. The output file (which displays words and their corresponding number of occurrences) came fine until the number of words read (program calculated) was nearly 12500 (nearly 2500 nodes). Above that, the output file did not make sense.

I tried running the program in Code::blocks and Visual Studio Express 2010, but the program crashed in both the cases (Probably something terribly wrong with my coding).

I'm an amateur programmer and find this problem extremely difficult to solve.

Additional (Edited after suggestions from the comments): 'n' returns a NULL after 7754 words.

Please provide me a solution to circumvent this problem by code or by using another compiler.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

FILE *wp=fopen("OUTPUT.txt","w");
FILE *cp=fopen("Taken.txt","w");
char c,tword[25],t=0;
struct words* create(char tword[]);
int addword(char tword[]);
void display(int i);
int most(int i);
int sort(int i);

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    long int total=0;
    FILE *fp=fopen("NOVEL.txt","r");
    do
    {
        c=fgetc(fp);
        if((c!=' ')&&(c!=EOF)&&(c!='.')&&(c!='\n'))
        {
            if((isalpha(c)||c=='-'))
            {
                if(t!=0)
                {
                    tword[i++]=t;
                    t=0;
                }
                tword[i]=c;
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                if(i!=0)
                    t=c;
                continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            total++;
            tword[i]=0;
            strupr(tword);
            addword(tword);
            i=0;
            t=0;
        }
    }while(!feof(fp));
    fclose(fp);
    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
          sort(i);
          display(i);
          most(i);
    }
    fprintf(wp,"\nTotal number of words: %ld",total);
    fclose(wp);
    fclose(cp);
    return 0;
}

struct words
{
    char word[15];
    long int count;
    struct words *next;
}*n,*temp,*curr,*prev,*alph[26];

struct words* create(char tword[])
{
    n=(struct words*)malloc(sizeof(struct words));
    strcpy(n->word,tword);
    n->count=1;
    return n;
}

int addword(char tword[])
{
    if((tword[0]=='\0')||(!isalpha(tword[0])))
    {
        if(tword[0]!='\0')
            fprintf(cp,"The discarded word: %s\n",tword);
        return 0;
    }
    temp=alph[tword[0]%'A'];
    if(temp==0)
    {
        alph[tword[0]%'A']=create(tword);
        alph[tword[0]%'A']->next=0;
    }
    else
    {
        curr=temp;
        while((strcmp(curr->word,tword)<0)&&curr)
        {
            prev=curr;
            curr=curr->next;
        }
        if(strcmp(curr->word,tword)==0)
        {
            curr->count++;
            return 0;
        }
        if(curr==temp)
        {
             n=create(tword);
             alph[tword[0]%'A']=n;
             alph[tword[0]%'A']->next=curr;
        }
        else if(curr==0)
        {
            n=create(tword);
            prev->next=n;
            n->next=0;
        }
        else
        {
            n=create(tword);
            prev->next=n;
            n->next=curr;
        }
        fprintf(cp,"Added word: %s\n",n->word);
    }
    return 0;
}

void display(int i)
{
    int space=0;
    curr=alph[i];
    fprintf(wp,"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tWords beginning with %c\n",'A'+i);
    while(curr)
    {
        if(space%5==0)
        {
            fprintf(wp,"\n");
        }
        else fprintf(wp,"\t");
        space++;
        fprintf(wp,"%25s :%4ld",curr->word,curr->count);
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    fprintf(wp,"\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNumber of words "
      "beginning with %c : %3d",'A'+i,space);
}

int most(int i)
{
    char tword[25];
    curr=alph[i];
    if(curr==0)
    {
        fprintf(wp,"\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNo words"
              " starting with %c\n\n",'A'+i);
        return 0;
    }
    long int grt=curr->count;
    strcpy(tword,curr->word);
    while(curr!=0)
    {
        if(grt<(curr->count))
        {
            grt=curr->count;
            strcpy(tword,curr->word);
        }
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    fprintf(wp,"\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMost repeated "
      "%c word is %s (%ld times)\n\n",'A'+i,tword,grt);
    return 0;
}

int sort(int i)
{
    char tempword[25];
    long int tempint;
    curr=alph[i];
    while(curr)
    {
        temp=curr->next;
        while(temp)
        {
            if(temp->count>curr->count)
            {
                strcpy(tempword,curr->word);
                strcpy(curr->word,temp->word);
                strcpy(temp->word,tempword);
                tempint=temp->count;
                temp->count=curr->count;
                curr->count=tempint;
            }
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: 1) `char c` --> `int c`. 2) `while(!feof(fp));` --> `while(c != EOF);`

Comment: @chux was thinking about the same. Depending on the size of your book I would even go further and make it a `unsigned long`.

Comment: check the return value of `malloc()`. Always. Not only if you *suspect* memory shortage.

Comment: And don't cast the result of malloc.

Comment: @mfro You don't always need to check the malloc return value. On linux its pointless boilerplate (you probably should for an embedded application)

Comment: Turbo C is 25 years old and pretty much obsolete.  You should avoid using it unless there's a really good reason why you need it — which, for a beginner programmer who has access to Code::Blocks and Visual Studio, is unlikely.

Comment: @user3121023 'n' did return a NULL after 7754 words. What do I do now?

Comment: I'd clean up a lot of the code. C is hard enough as it is, but getting rid of the **global file vars**, hard coded character array lengths in the struct, and the struct names (curr, temp, alph) will declutter and make it easier for you to read your code.

Comment: Pace, SteveCox: that's nonsense. `malloc()` will return `NULL` on Linux when virtual memory is exhausted like it will on any other platform on the planet.

Comment: Turbo C is a really bad compiler, don't use it. But what's really sad is that even this old crap compiler has better standard compliance than Visual Studio 2013. So out of those 3 alternatives, I'd strongly recommend Code::Blocks with GCC.

Comment: @mfro actually, by defualt, linux doesn't promise you that a non-null implies there will actually be memory to use. and it will kill your process if it runs out of memory. regardless, dont check every single malloc, that's crazy. Do something like `memstatus = memstatus && malloc(size);` and then check multiple allocations at once.

Comment: `strcpy(n->word,tword);` is a problem if `strlen(tword) >= 15`.

Comment: Yeah, @chux is right. Replace the word field with `char* word` and malloc that separately according to wordlen.

Comment: BTW `FILE *wp=fopen("OUTPUT.txt","w");` : You can not initialize such global variable in C. I suspect you are using C++ instead of C.